# I can't get the hair on my model to render, or even apply color. (Buzzcut)

Tags: particles, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to give my model a buzzcut. I went through all the proper steps that I know of. Creating a vertex group, all these things with the particle system and everything, but when I go to change the color of the model's hair (black), it turns the entire model that color and I can't figure out why. Additionally, when I render the model, the hair does not appear. I've been stuck on this for three days now. Thanks :)

Add: This picture is what I am now faced with. Changed the color of the scalp and not the hair.[image]

Comment: To increase the clarity of your question please include screen snapshots.  Include successful and unsuccessful parts of your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A few possibilities are (assuming using cycles):

- For the mesh, you should make two materials; the first material is for the mesh itself, the second material is used to select it from the 'particle systems' to use for the hair material. To change the hair material, you should only modify the second material, since the first material is used for the mesh (for example face color). In image, the first material, light colored is used for the mesh and second material, dark colored is used for the hair and is also selected in the particle systems.
  [image]
- When you are in particle edit mode, then you don't see the hair when you render it or use rendered shading. You should see the hair, when you are in vertex paint mode, edit mode, object mode, sculpt mode, weight paint mode or texture mode.

But I am not sure if this is what you mean :)

Comment: Actually, I think that might just solve my issue, thanks! I'm going to check it out and see what I can do!

Comment: Yes, there's the hair in vertex paint! Thanks! Now to find a YouTube tutorial on how to implement THIS feature.

Comment: Ok, so I don't know how to separate the hair material from the main body of the model. I can create new materials all day, but I can't figure out how to link them to the hair material and not the main object.

Comment: I added image for clarity :)

Comment: I tried to do that, by making the vertex group for hair a different mesh, but I did not succeed. I think I must have done it incorrectly.