# How to make hair material different from the plane itself?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

In Cycles Render, I added hair to a plane (as I was making a grass field) and I don't seem to know how to make the actual flat plane's material different from the hairs themselves, because I'd like to make the plane have an image texture and the hairs have a yellow-like color to them, but of course, if I attempt to make the material yellow-ish, the plane AND the hairs will become yellow. I'm done with the plane, I just want to control the hairs' materials.

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31778/i-cant-get-the-hair-on-my-model-to-render-or-even-apply-color-buzzcut/31784#31784

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can change the strand's material by adding another material slot in the *materials* pane, then go to *particle settings* panel > *render* rollout and select the new material in the *material slot* dropdown list.

Add a new material slot:
[image]

And select it in the particle settings:
[image]